# Turning off keyboard animation for activity

Tags: android, android-animation, android-softkeyboard

When user clicks/selects EditText a (soft) keyboard in shown. I need it to be shown as quickly as possible. By default the keyboard is shown with animation, which slows down the whole process.

I succeeded to disable "keyboard showing animation" by manually turning it off in Android settings:

- Turning off animations in developer mode: http://pocketnow.com/android/how-to-disable-screen-animations-in-android-40-ics
- Turning off animations for HTC Sense: http://forums.androidcentral.com/t-mobile-htc-sensation/92195-turning-off-animations.html
- ...

This is great, but many of our customers fail to set this setting on their own.

Is there a way to disable keyboard animations programatically for a given activity? Something like `keyboardAnimation="off"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this manually, however, you NEED to do this manually, by overriding some listeners.
Basically this is what you do when the user clicks the EditText:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
imm.showSoftInputFromInputMethod(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

It's pretty generic so should work on most (or all) devices.

Comment: This does not seem to work. Android 4.1.2, Acer B1-710.