# Turn off keyboard slide animation in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-softkeyboard, soft-keyboard

Whenever the soft-keyboard is invoked in the android application, I would like the keyboard to open and close instantly. By default the keyboard has a slide up / down animation, but this can be disabled when [turning off the interface animation in your android device.](https://mcmw.abilitynet.org.uk/how-disable-interface-animations-android-10)

My question is, can we disable the keyboard animation in the app using Kotlin? If not, can we at least disable and enable all app animations programmatically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turning off keyboard animation for activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25805751/turning-off-keyboard-animation-for-activity)

Comment: @TomJoney Our questions are similar, but that solution did not resolve it for me. It merely just invokes / hides the keyboard, but the animation still remains.